# AngularJS: Config $routeProvider after $http request

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I need to config `$routeProvider` after ajax request, but i can not using `$http` in config, means following code causes error:

```
module.config(['$routeProvider','$http',function ($routeProvider,$http) {}
```

and `$routeProvider` can not accessed in controller!

I need this approach for considering who can see what page as index page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `$routeProvider` from config object to your controller. For example

in your route config file you write:

```
 .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'template.html',
                    controller: 'MyController',
                    controllerAs: 'main',
                    resolve: {
                        myRouteConfig: function(){
                            return $routeProvider;
                        }
                    }
                })
```

and in controller you can inject it like a dependency

```
function MyController(myRouteConfig) {
   myRouteConfig.when ...... 
}
```

working example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manar007/mcVfK/596/)

Comment: myRouteProvider can not inject in Controller: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17/$injector/unpr?p0=myRouteProviderProvider%20%3C-%20myRouteProvider

Comment: it seems naming convention issue , I updated example

Comment: the problem exists yet: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.17/$injector/unpr?p0=myRouteConfigProvider%20%3C-%20myRouteConfig

Comment: I have added the fiddle link